# Kotlin Coroutines - Async Await

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

In his article about Structured Concurrency in Kotlin (https://medium.com/@elizarov/structured-concurrency-722d765aa952), Roman Elizarov explains parallel decomposition by giving the following example:

```
coroutineScope { 
    val deferred1 = async { loadImage(name1) }
    val deferred2 = async { loadImage(name2) }
    combineImages(deferred1.await(), deferred2.await())
}
```

Obviously, this code is self-explanatory. However will we get the same result if we write this instead

```
coroutineScope { 
    val result1 = async { loadImage(name1) }.await()
    val result2 = async { loadImage(name2) }.await()
    combineImages(result1, result2)
}
```

Meaning, will both async still run in parallel or the 2nd async call will never run until result1 is available ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example 1:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking<Unit> {
    val time = measureTimeMillis {
        val one = async {
            delay(1000)
            return@async 1
        }
        val two = async {
            delay(3000)
            return@async 2
        }
        println("The answer is ${one.await() + two.await()}")
    }
    println("Completed in $time ms")
}
```

Result 1:

```
The answer is 3
Completed in 3041 ms
```

Example 2:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking<Unit> {
    val time = measureTimeMillis {
        val one = async {
            delay(1000)
            return@async 1
        }.await()
        val two = async {
            delay(3000)
            return@async 2
        }.await()
        println("The answer is ${one + two}")
    }
    println("Completed in $time ms")
}
```

Result 2:

```
The answer is 3
Completed in 4043 ms
```

Check out this link for the official documentation for [Concurrent using async](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/docs/composing-suspending-functions.md#concurrent-using-async)

**Conclusion**

async-await-async-await will result in pure sequential code

async-async-await-await will run in parallel